# Sqoop running into local job runner mode

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

When i run sqoop am not sure why it runs into local job runner mode and then says that i have provided invalid jobtracker url for LocalJobRunner. Can anyone tell whats going on?

```
$ bin/sqoop import -jt myjobtracker:50070 --connect jdbc:mysql://mydbhost.com/mydata --username foo --password bar --as-parquetfile --table campaigns --target-dir hdfs://myhdfs:8020/user/myself/campaigns
14/08/20 21:04:50 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-SNAPSHOT
14/08/20 21:04:50 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
14/08/20 21:04:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
14/08/20 21:04:51 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/08/20 21:04:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `campaigns` AS t LIMIT 1
14/08/20 21:04:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `campaigns` AS t LIMIT 1
14/08/20 21:04:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `campaigns` AS t LIMIT 1
14/08/20 21:04:51 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-myself/compile/6acdb40688239f19ddf86a1290ad6c64/campaigns.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/08/20 21:04:54 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-myself/compile/6acdb40688239f19ddf86a1290ad6c64/campaigns.jar
14/08/20 21:04:54 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
14/08/20 21:04:54 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
14/08/20 21:04:54 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
14/08/20 21:04:54 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
14/08/20 21:04:54 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of campaigns
14/08/20 21:04:54 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
14/08/20 21:04:54 WARN mapred.JobConf: The variable mapred.child.ulimit is no longer used.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
14/08/20 21:04:54 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/08/20 21:04:56 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/08/20 21:04:56 INFO mapreduce.Cluster: Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider due to error: Invalid "mapreduce.jobtracker.address" configuration value for LocalJobRunner : "myjobtracker:50070"
14/08/20 21:04:56 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:myself (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
14/08/20 21:04:56 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1235)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:665)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem, i was running sqoop 1.4.5 and pointing it to the latest hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.4.0 which had the yarn stuff also thats why it was complaining.

When i pointed sqoop to hadoop-0.20/2.0.0-cdh4.4.0 (MR1 i think) it worked.

Comment: Good to know that. I saw you are already using `--as-parquetfile`. Have fun.